# How to get clean text from MediaWiki markup format using mwparserfromhell or a simple parser in python?

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am trying to get clean sentences from the Wikipedia page of a species.

For instance *Abeis durangensis* (pid = 1268312). Using the Wikipedia API in python to obtain the Wikipedia page:

```
import requests
pid = 1268312
q = {'action' : 'query',
     'pageids': pid,
     'prop'   : 'revisions',
     'rvprop' : 'content',
     'format' : 'json'}
result = requests.get(eswiki_URI, params=q).json()
wikitext = result["query"]["pages"].values()[0]["revisions"][0]["*"]
```

gives:

```
{{Ficha de taxón
| name = ''Abies durangensis''
| image = Abies tamazula dgo.jpg 
| status = LR/lc
| status_ref =<ref>Conifer Specialist Group 1998.  [http://www.iucnredlist.org/search/details.php/42279/all ''Abies durangensis''].   [http://www.iucnredlist.org 2006 IUCN Red List of Threatened Species. ]  Downloaded on 10 July 2007.</ref>
| regnum = [[Plantae]]
| divisio = [[Pinophyta]]
| classis = [[Pinopsida]]
| ordo = [[Pinales]]
| familia = [[Pinaceae]]
| genus = ''[[Abies]]'' 
| binomial = '''''Abies durangensis'''''
| binomial_authority = [[Maximino Martínez|Martínez]]<ref name=ipni>{{ cite web |url=http://www.ipni.org:80/ipni/idPlantNameSearch.do;jsessionid=0B15264060FDA0DCF216D997C89185EC?id=676563-1&back_page=%2Fipni%2FeditSimplePlantNameSearch.do%3Bjsessionid%3D0B15264060FDA0DCF216D997C89185EC%3Ffind_wholeName%3DAbies%2Bdurangensis%26output_format%3Dnormal |title=Plant Name Details for ''Abies durangensis'' |publisher=[[International Plant Names Index|IPNI]] |accessdate=6 de octubre de 2009}}</ref>
| synonyms = 
}}
'''''Abies durangensis''''' es una [[especie]] de [[conífera]] perteneciente a la familia [[Pinaceae]]. Son [[endémica]]s de [[México]] donde se encuentran en [[Durango]], [[Chihuahua]], [[Coahuila]], [[Jalisco]] y [[Sinaloa]]. También es conocido como 'Árbol de Coahuila' y 'pino mexicano'.<ref name=cje>{{ cite web |url=http://www.conifers.org/pi/ab/durangensis.htm |title=''Abies durangaensis'' description |author=Christopher J. Earle |date=11 de junio de 2006 |accessdate=6 de octubre de 2009}}</ref> 

== Descripción ==
Es un [[árbol]] que alcanza los 40 metros de altura con un [[Tronco (botánica)|tronco]] recto que tiene 150&nbsp;cm de diámetro. Las [[rama]]s son horizontales y la [[corteza (árbol)|corteza]] de color gris. Las [[hoja]]s son verde brillante de 20–35&nbsp;mm de longitud por 1-1.5&nbsp;mm de ancho. Tiene los conos de [[semilla]]s erectos en ramas laterales sobre un corto [[pedúnculo]]. Las [[semilla]]s son [[resina|resinosas]] con una [[núcula]] amarilla con alas.

== Taxonomía ==
''Abies durangensis'' fue descrita por [[Maximino Martínez]] y publicado en ''[[Anales del instituto de Biología de la Universidad Nacional de México]]'' 13: 2. 1942.<ref name = Trop>{{cita web |url=http://www.tropicos.org/Name/24901700 |título= ''{{PAGENAME}}''|fechaacceso=21 de enero de 2013 |formato= |obra=  Tropicos.org. [[Missouri Botanical Garden]]}}</ref>
;[[Etimología]]:
'''''Abies''''': nombre genérico que viene del nombre [[latin]]o de ''[[Abies alba]]''.<ref>[http://www.calflora.net/botanicalnames/pageAB-AM.html En Nombres Botánicos]</ref>

'''''durangensis''''': [[epíteto]] geográfico que alude a su localización en [[Durango]].
;Variedades:
* ''Abies durangensis var. coahuilensis'' (I. M. Johnst.) Martínez 
;[[sinonimia (biología)|Sinonimia]]:
* ''Abies durangensis subsp. neodurangensis'' (Debreczy, I.Rácz & R.M.Salazar) Silba'
* ''Abies neodurangensis'' Debreczy, I.Rácz & R.M.Salazar<ref>[http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl/record/kew-2609816 ''{{PAGENAME}}'' en PlantList]</ref><ref name = Kew>{{cita web|url=http://apps.kew.org/wcsp/namedetail.do?name_id=2609816 |título=''{{PAGENAME}}'' |work= World Checklist of Selected Plant Families}}</ref>
;''var. coahuilensis'' (I.M.Johnst.) Martínez
* ''Abies coahuilensis'' I.M.Johnst.
* ''Abies durangensis subsp. coahuilensis'' (I.M.Johnst.) Silba
== Véase también ==
* [[Terminología descriptiva de las plantas]]
* [[Anexo:Cronología de la botánica]]
* [[Historia de la Botánica]]
* [[Pinaceae#Descripción|Características de las pináceas]]
== Referencias ==
{{listaref}}
== Bibliografía ==
# CONABIO. 2009. Catálogo taxonómico de especies de México. 1. In Capital Nat. México. CONABIO, Mexico City.
== Enlaces externos ==
{{commonscat}}
{{wikispecies|Abies}}
* http://web.archive.org/web/http://ww.conifers.org/pi/ab/durangensis.htm
* http://www.catalogueoflife.org/search.php

[[Categoría:Abies|durangensis]]
[[Categoría:Plantas descritas en 1942]]
[[Categoría:Plantas descritas por Martínez]]
```

I am interested in the (unmarked) text just after the infobox, the gloss:

> Abies durangensis es una especie de conífera perteneciente a la familia Pinaceae. Son endémicas de México donde se encuentran en Durango, Chihuahua, Coahuila, Jalisco y Sinaloa. También es conocido como 'Árbol de Coahuila' y 'pino mexicano'.

Until now i consulted https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers so i found that mwparserfromhell is the less complicated parser in python. However, i dont see clearly how to do what i pretend. When i use the example proposed in the documentation i just can't see where the gloss is.

```
for t in templates:
    print(t.name).encode('utf-8')
    print(t.params)

Ficha de taxón

[u" name = ''Abies durangensis''\n", u' image = Abies tamazula dgo.jpg \n', u' status = LR/lc\n', u" status_ref =<ref>Conifer Specialist Group 1998.  [http://www.iucnredlist.org/search/details.php/42279/all ''Abies durangensis''].   [http://www.iucnredlist.org 2006 IUCN Red List of Threatened Species. ]  Downloaded on 10 July 2007.</ref>\n", u' regnum = [[Plantae]]\n', u' divisio = [[Pinophyta]]\n', u' classis = [[Pinopsida]]\n', u' ordo = [[Pinales]]\n', u' familia = [[Pinaceae]]\n', u" genus = ''[[Abies]]'' \n", u" binomial = '''''Abies durangensis'''''\n", u" binomial_authority = [[Maximino Mart\xednez|Mart\xednez]]<ref name=ipni>{{ cite web |url=http://www.ipni.org:80/ipni/idPlantNameSearch.do;jsessionid=0B15264060FDA0DCF216D997C89185EC?id=676563-1&back_page=%2Fipni%2FeditSimplePlantNameSearch.do%3Bjsessionid%3D0B15264060FDA0DCF216D997C89185EC%3Ffind_wholeName%3DAbies%2Bdurangensis%26output_format%3Dnormal |title=Plant Name Details for ''Abies durangensis'' |publisher=[[International Plant Names Index|IPNI]] |accessdate=6 de octubre de 2009}}</ref>\n", u' synonyms = \n']
 cite web 
[u'url=http://www.ipni.org:80/ipni/idPlantNameSearch.do;jsessionid=0B15264060FDA0DCF216D997C89185EC?id=676563-1&back_page=%2Fipni%2FeditSimplePlantNameSearch.do%3Bjsessionid%3D0B15264060FDA0DCF216D997C89185EC%3Ffind_wholeName%3DAbies%2Bdurangensis%26output_format%3Dnormal ', u"title=Plant Name Details for ''Abies durangensis'' ", u'publisher=[[International Plant Names Index|IPNI]] ', u'accessdate=6 de octubre de 2009']
 cite web 
[u'url=http://www.conifers.org/pi/ab/durangensis.htm ', u"title=''Abies durangaensis'' description ", u'author=Christopher J. Earle ', u'date=11 de junio de 2006 ', u'accessdate=6 de octubre de 2009']
cita web 
[u'url=http://www.tropicos.org/Name/24901700 ', u"t\xedtulo= ''{{PAGENAME}}''", u'fechaacceso=21 de enero de 2013 ', u'formato= ', u'obra=  Tropicos.org. [[Missouri Botanical Garden]]']
PAGENAME
[]
PAGENAME
[]
cita web
[u'url=http://apps.kew.org/wcsp/namedetail.do?name_id=2609816 ', u"t\xedtulo=''{{PAGENAME}}'' ", u'work= World Checklist of Selected Plant Families']
PAGENAME
[]
listaref
[]
commonscat
[]
wikispecies
[u'Abies']
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of torturing yourself with parsing of something that's not even expressable in formal grammar, use the [TextExtracts API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts#API):

`https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=1&titles=Abies%20durangensis&format=json`

gives the following output:

> Abies durangensis es una especie de conífera perteneciente a la
>   familia Pinaceae. Son endémicas de México donde se encuentran en
>   Durango, Chihuahua, Coahuila, Jalisco y Sinaloa. También es conocido
>   como 'Árbol de Coahuila' y 'pino mexicano'.
>
> == Descripción ==
>
> Es un árbol que alcanza los 40 metros de altura con un tronco recto que tiene 150 cm de diámetro. Las ramas son
>   horizontales y la corteza de color gris. Las hojas son verde brillante
>   de 20–35 mm de longitud por 1-1.5 mm de ancho. Tiene los conos de
>   semillas erectos en ramas laterales sobre un corto pedúnculo. Las
>   semillas son resinosas con una núcula amarilla con alas.
>
> [...]

Append `&exintro=1` to the URL if you need only the lead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wikitextparser](https://pypi.org/project/wikitextparser/)

If `wikitext` has your text string, all you need is:

```
import wikitextparser
parsed = wikitextparser.parse(wikitext)
```

then you can get the plain text portion of the whole page or a particular section, for example: `parsed.sections[1].plain_text()` will give you the plain text of the second section of the page which seems to be what you are looking for.